# Стоит ли публиковать NuGet-пакет для нескольких платформ, когда достаточно функционала .NET Standard?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Есть приложения на .NET Framework 4.7.1 и на .NETCore 3.1.
Написана библиотека, которая будет упаковываться в NuGet-пакет и использоваться в обоих приложениях.
В принципе, тут подходит вариант публикации на netstandard2.0:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Но можно опубликовать сразу две версии:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Вопрос: стоит ли публиковать версии для двух платформ?
По идее, в проект на платформе .NET Core будет подтягиваться версия для .NET Core, для Framework'а — netstandard2.0.
Есть ли какая-то разница между netcoreapp3.1 и netstandard2.0 (например в производительности) или они абсолютно одинаковы в этом плане и не надо публиковать в двух вариантах?

Comment: Думаю хотя бы в плане тестирования и дебага разумнее будет публиковать только standart

Comment: [Cross-platform targeting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting). По умолчанию используйте только .NET Standard. Multi-targeting используйте только в том случае, если необходим доступ к framework-specific APIs.